# Twisted RevereProxy altering response headers

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to write a reverse proxy that adds some headers and remove some headers from the backend response. I've looked into documentation and saw that there is a `ReverseProxyRequest`. However I can't see a `ReverseProxyRespone` and am not clear if methods like `headerReceived` are from the request or from the response. Any help? Pointers to documentation?

### Thanks,

Miki

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `headerReceived` method in [the API documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.2/api/twisted.web.proxy.ReverseProxyRequest.html).

However, the older, more ambiguous names, like `headers`, have all been deprecated - you should be using the hopefully more clearly-named `requestHeaders` and `responseHeaders`.

Comment: `headerRecieved` is in the [HTTPChannel](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.2/api/twisted.web.http.HTTPChannel.html) class.